# How to add flip card animation with CSS keyframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I built a blackjack game. Now I want the cards of the dealer, when they appear, to flip from back to the front. I built the keyframes in CSS but I can't apply it on the JS file.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function deal() {
    if (newgame == true) {
        var random = Math.floor((Math.random() * 13));
        var UserCards = document.getElementById('user');
        var card = document.createElement('img');
        card.setAttribute("width", 450);
        card.setAttribute("src", images[random]);
        UserCards.appendChild(card);
        UserCards.className ='myDIV';
        checkUserScore += cards[random];  
        if (checkUserScore > 21)
        {
            UserCards.appendChild(card);
            alert("you hit more than 21");
        }          
    }
```

*EDIT: Did the OP leave out the function closing brace when pasting the code, or is that an actual error?*

**CSS**

```
<style>
        .myDIV {
            margin: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-image:url(media/cards/UpsideDown.jpg);
            color: white;
            animation: mymove 5s infinite;
        }

        @keyframes mymove {
            50% {
                transform: rotate(360deg);
                background-image:url(media/cards/QC.jpg);
            }
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Please show your markup. Neither JS nor CSS mean anything without it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you searched the [web](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_card.asp)?

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front,
.flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: #bbb;
  color: black;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: #2980b9;
  color: white;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<h1>Card Flip with Text</h1>
<h3>Hover over the image below:</h3>

<div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
      <img src="img_avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:300px;height:300px;">
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
      <h1>John Doe</h1>
      <p>Architect & Engineer</p>
      <p>We love that guy</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes i did , i saw what you posted , i dont know how to make the card flip by it's own without clicking , i want it to flip after an image is appended child activaited